# Sending StringIO object to vertica copy command

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, vertica

I am extracting CSV files from an Excel worksheet using `openpyxl` in **Python 3.4**. Since my python version is 3.x, I have to use StringIO instead of BytesIO to make InMemory CSV files.

All is fine and well in Excel to CSV conversion, BUT I am required to send the file object to Vertica copy command `cursorV.copy(copy_qry, fileObj)`.

The command worked fine with BytesIO file object, but with StringIO it gives error:

> Can't concat bytes to str

**Is there a way to send StringIO file object to vertica copy commmand?**

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by converting StringIO object to BytesIO using following code:

```
c = io.BytesIO(a.getvalue().encode())
```